# Algorithm to mix pre-mixed colors to a defined ratio?

Tags: php, algorithm, mixing

There is a problem I don't know how to solve. I need to achieve a given ratio of Cyan, Magenta and Yellow (CMYK without the K) while using pre-mixed colors in bottles with different sizes.

In every task any number of 3+ bottles is possible (3, ..., n) and the bottle sizes are different as well.

I've made this graphic for a better understanding: [Color Mixing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtvN1m.png)

**The goal:**
How many times each bottle has to be added to get a given ratio of CMY?

The restrictions are:

1. Every bottle has to be used for at least one time
2. A bottle has to be used completely

---

**What I've already tried**

I tried to solve it with gauss elimination. If there are just 3 bottles it will work well but on 4+ bottles it won't.

I also tried a loop and add the best possible bottle to get the given ratio based on the actual ratio. In some cases this leads to a huge number of loops and takes a lot of time or fails.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you clarify your setting? You ask for "how much" of each has to be added, and yet restriction (2) is that a bottle has to be used completely. Also restriction (1) is not clear: are you solving multiple such problems, over which each bottle has to used atleast once?

Comment: Sorry my fault. Every bottle can be used as often as it's necessary to get the given ratio but 1 time is minimum for each bottle. If a bottle get used it has to be used completely not just half of its contents for example. I'll edit the question.